# Using backspace on VIM search and replace

Tags: search, vim, replace, backspace

What character do I use for the newline on Vim search and replace commands?

I'm trying to make this:

```
1, 
2, 
3, 
4, 
5
```

to this: `1, 2, 3, 4 ,5`

So i thought of writing something like: `:%s/$/\b/g`

But it didn't work even if I set: `:set magic`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: You're trying to move the comma over one space?

Comment: I"ve edited my question, each number is on a different line.

Comment: It looks like you just want to join those rows. Since you are using Vim, select the rows in visual mode and press `J` to join them together.

Comment: This solves my problem, but just out of curiosity: is there a Vim command that represents a "backspace character" on Vim Search and Replace?

Comment: A "backspace" character doesn't really make sense here. What you probably want is to replace the matched text with nothing.

Comment: please fix the title of this question.  It has absolutely nothing to do with backspace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Newlines are represented by `\n`.

So, with such a simple example, you can replace every newline with:

```
%s/\n//g
```

You can replace each comma, followed by optional whitespace until the end of a line with a space, like so:

```
:%s/,\s*$\n/, /g
```

---

Of course, the `J` operator will most likely suit your needs just fine as well (try <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> within the block you wish to concatenate. Or to automatically line wrap per your `textwidth` setting: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for giving both Search and Replace and Visual solutions, the :%s/\n/ /g worked fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need `:s` this will do the job:

```
gg5J
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this search and replace command:

```
:%s/,\n/, /g
```

The `\n` character matches the newline in the search string.

As a sidenote, if you want to insert a `newline character` in the replace string make sure to use `\r` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative would be the `:join` command.

```
:%j
```

For more information see

```
:h :j
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual mode to select the lines that you want to join

```
ggvGJ
```

`gg` takes you to the top of the document.
`v` puts you in visual mode
`G` takes you to the bottom of the document (thereby highlighting all rows)
`J` joins all rows in the selected range.